# how to execute a function after closing a child window in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I want to execute a function after closing a child window , here is my code, this do not work as expected

```
Preferences *dialog = new Preferences();
connect(dialog,SIGNAL(destroyed()),this,SLOT(LoadSettings()));
dialog->show();
```

Edit: It seems that I mistakenly chose QmainWIndow for preference dialog :-( , can I fix this without porting it into Qdialog? Or is there any easy way to port Qmainwindow ui to Qdialog ui

Comment: What does "do not work as expected" mean? Does it compile? Are there error messages? What can be observed that leads you do this conclusion?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how it doesn't work as expected? Are you receiving any errors? What is expected?

Comment: arne crush edited question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Preferences *dialog = new Preferences();
connect(dialog,SIGNAL(destroyed()),this,SLOT(LoadSettings()));
dialog->exec();
delete dialog;
```

Comment: You could create the dialog in the stack instead and avoid using `delete` operator.